# SimpleJdbcInsert mixes column names from different databases in MySQL

Tags: spring-jdbc

I have recently upgraded spring framework from 5.0.3 to 5.3.12 and mysql from 5.7 to 8.

I am adding new columns in DB and corresponding fields in model class. but it is unable to store the value for newly added fields in DB. I have debugged the program the values are patched in model class but after the *simplejdbcinsert* api being called the values doesnt persist in DB.

the code is like this -

DAO call -

```
      logger.debug("Party Insert: " + logStr);
      ID = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource).withTableName("TBL_PARTY")
      .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("Id").executeAndReturnKey(sqlParams).intValue();
```

model class -

```
public class Party extends GenericEntity{


private String partyType, name, partyCode, PANNumber;
    private String registrationId;
private String WebsiteAddress;
private boolean isActive = true;    
private String externalID;
private double openingBalance, closingBalance;

// new columns - fields
private String temp;
private int tempInt;
private byte tempTyniInt;
private boolean tempBol;


public String getTemp() {
    return temp;
}

public void setTemp(String temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
}

public String getWebsiteAddress() {
    return WebsiteAddress;
}
public void setWebsiteAddress(String websiteAddress) {
    WebsiteAddress = websiteAddress;
}
public String getPartyCode() {
    return partyCode;
}
public void setPartyCode(String partyCode) {
    this.partyCode = partyCode;
}
public String getPartyType() {
    return partyType;
}
public void setPartyType(String partyType) {
    this.partyType = partyType;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getRegistrationId() {
    return registrationId;
}
public void setRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
    this.registrationId = registrationId;
}
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    
    return ReflectionUtil.compareObjects(this, obj);
}

public String getExternalID() {
    return externalID;
}
public void setExternalID(String externalID) {
    this.externalID = externalID;
}
public double getOpeningBalance() {
    return openingBalance;
}
public void setOpeningBalance(double openingBalance) {
    this.openingBalance = openingBalance;
}
public double getClosingBalance() {
    return closingBalance;
}
public void setClosingBalance(double closingBalance) {
    this.closingBalance = closingBalance;
}
public String toString()
{
    return StringUtil.objectToString(this).concat(super.toString());
}
public String getPANNumber() {
    return PANNumber;
}
public void setPANNumber(String pANNumber) {
    PANNumber = pANNumber;
}
public boolean getIsActive() {
    return isActive;
}
public void setIsActive(boolean isActive) {
    this.isActive = isActive;
}

public int getTempInt() {
    return tempInt;
}

public void setTempInt(int tempInt) {
    this.tempInt = tempInt;
}

public int getTempTyniInt() {
    return tempTyniInt;
}

public void setTempTyniInt(byte tempTyniInt) {
    this.tempTyniInt = tempTyniInt;
}

public boolean getTempBol() {
    return tempBol;
}

public void setTempBol(boolean tempBol) {
    this.tempBol = tempBol;
}
```

the new columns(fields) are - temp, tempInt, tempTyniInt, tempBol.

FYI - after the up-gradation we have changed the DB collation for all the tables from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` & charset from `latin1` to `utf8mb4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution from the source -
*https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22015*

someone commented -

The default value of property **nullCatalogMeansCurrent** has been changed in mysql-driver 5.x and 8.x. In 5.x, the default value is true, and in 8.x false, so in 5.x **DatabaseMetaData.getTables** will return tables exactly from 'example1', and in 8.x **DatabaseMetaData.getTables** will return tables not only from 'example1' but from all databases, that's why the SQL will be changed to 'INSERT INTO persons (lastname) VALUES (?)'.
Workaround, add **nullCatalogMeansCurrent=true** to conn url when using mysql-driver 8.x, all tests pass successfully.